# Passing a Method into an AsyncTask using Reflection considered "bad practice"?

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-asynctask

My situation looks like this:
I have an object containing two methods.
Some times I want to run method 1 in an AsyncTask, and other times I want to run method 2.
Using Reflection/Method I can pass in the method I want to be run in the AsyncTask as a parameter, and otherwise I have to implement separate AsyncTasks for the different methods.

Is it considered bad practice to pass a Method into an AsyncTask? I'm very new to the concept of Reflection, and it sounds pretty powerful, but I'm not sure if it is considered "bad"?

Comment: Surely you can accomplish the same thing without reflection. For example, by passing a flag to indicate which method to execute.

Comment: Yes, of course. This just seemed interesting, and I'm curious as to if this is actually a viable way of doing it.

Comment: Certainly it's possible, but I wouldn't use anything like that in a released app, especially if you have complete control over the source. Reflection adds unnecessary overhead, and can sometimes be "unsafe". If you're just testing, "playing around" with reflection at the moment, then by all means, give it a go. But generally, if you don't _have_ to use reflection, don't.

Comment: There are just too many ways to botch something with reflection. Sometimes your reflection isn't what you think it is, and if you change something somewhere and forget to alter your reflection code you will likely run into issues.